# Return a HTML string, but have certain index ranges wrapped with html tags

Tags: javascript, html, xml, node.js

I need a function that can do the following,

- Return a string based on input from an array of strings
- Wrap html tags such as `<b>` and `<i>` to certain index ranges
- No unnecessary tags
- Syntactically correct

For example,

```
var arr = ['foo ', 'bar ', 'bam' ];

var styles = {
  b: [0, 1, 2], 
  i: [1, 2],
  sup: [0]
}

var str = theMagicFunction(arr, styles);

console.log(str);
//=  "<b><sup>foo </sup><i>bar bam</i></b>"
```

Just to be clear I am looking for a node.js, vanilla javascript solution. I don't feel the solution requires a XML Parser.

Comment: @dfsq the key `b` is the tag that I want wrapped, and the value `[0, 1, 2]` contains the indexes to where that tag should be applied on the array passed in to the function. In that case, I want the tag `<b>` applied to `foo`, `bar`, and `bam`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use loops to append tags at necessary indices. Try this basic implementation:

```
function theMagicFunction(arr, styles) {

    var stylesArr = [], key;

    for (key in styles) {
        stylesArr.push({key: key, idx: styles[key]});
    }

    stylesArr.sort(function(a, b) { 
        return a.idx.length - b.idx.length
    })
    .forEach(function(style) {
        style.idx.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
        arr[style.idx[0]] = '<' + style.key + '>' + arr[style.idx[0]];
        arr[style.idx[style.idx.length - 1]] += '</' + style.key + '>';
    });

    return arr.join('');
}
```

The idea is to apply tags from minimum word spans to maximum.

The result: `<b><sup>foo</sup><i>bar bam</i></b>`

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/8cHr3/

Comment: Hey thanks for this! There is a little bit of bug in the following case... http://jsfiddle.net/8cHr3/1/. Towards the end the `<b>` and `<i>` overlap. I guess there needs to be some logic to add an item to the `stylesArr` in the case some of the indexes overlap. I am hacking around on it, but if you have any ideas let me know. Thanks!